# How to make switched Outlet control on Switched Outlet on opposite side of room

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, smart-switch

Are there any on the Shelf products that allow light switches on one side of the room to control unswitched receptacles on the other side of the room? I know that you could do this with smart switches, but those are relatively expensive and I would I think that there is one that uses a RF transmitter and RF controlled relay.[image]

Comment: I take it the reason you want this is because you can't run wiring between the two points, even using a surface raceway (Wiremold)?

Comment: Ya. I don't want the hardware or anything because that would be a decent amount of work. Also surface wires look ugly.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a product that works just like industry standard, connected smart switches, but is not industry standard, not connected, and uses a proprietary radio frequency.

That wouldn't have much of a market, would it?  From what you're saying, it sounds like you see the market as "it's cheaper", and you hope that incompatibility and low feature set would make it *cheaper*.  That would certainly make it *worth less* ... but as far as "cheaper", nah, that's just not how production economics work.